# What happens when two ergospheres of oppositely spinning black holes of the same mass, axis of rotation, and speed of rotation approach?

Tags: black-holes, kerr-metric

What happens when two ergospheres of oppositely spinning black holes of the same mass, axis of rotation, and speed of rotation approach each other?
What would happen to the black holes in question?

Comment: A lot of gravitational radiation...